# What's going on my Eclipse? Getting Syntax error on everything

Tags: java, syntax

That's my simple code but it got 4 Syntax errors.

```
public class Program {
System.out.print("Hello World");
}
```

Screenshot with all the information: [Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qe4s9.png)

Comment: You should have a `main` method.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/84/getting-started-with-java-language/378/creating-your-first-java-program#t=20161227121421268916 and compare your attempt with that version of a "hello world" program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't execute the code exactly in the class. You may execute this one in a method or some statement.

For example, you can execute this code in `main` method like this:

```
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Or you can execute the code in static statement like this:

```
public class Program {
    static {
        System.out.println("Hello World 1");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Hello World 2");
    }
}
```

Remember, that static statement executes before the `main` method.

Hope, it helped you.